# RefTeX with biblatex field names

Tags: emacs, biblatex

I'm using RefTeX in EMACS. I have a bibliography file which uses biblatex's field names e.g. I have 'Journaltitle' instead of bibtex's 'Journal'. Here's an example entry:

```
@article{BerwickPietroskiYankamaChomsky2011,
    Author = {Berwick, Robert C. and Pietroski, Paul M. and Yankama, Beracah and Chomsky, Noam},
    Doi = {10.1111/j.1551-6709.2011.01189.x},
    Journaltitle = {Cognitive Science},
    Pages = {1207--1242},
    Title = {Poverty of the Stimulus Revisited},
    Volume = {35},
    Year = {2011}}
```

When I use `C-c [` everything works, but I don't see the 'Journaltitle' field displayed i.e. I don't see 'Cognitive Science'. This is because RefTeX is looking for 'Journal'; adding a 'Journal' field to the record results in it showing up.

Two questions:

1. Is that what's going on?
2. Can I tell RefTeX to look for biblatex fields? (The manual didn't help me.)

Comment: Look at function 'reftex-format-bib-entry'

Comment: @thisirs Where is that documented? It's not in the manual as far as I can see.

Comment: It is in the source file reftex-cite.el. You have to redefine it in your .emacs.

Comment: I think this would be worth reporting to the maintainers of `reftex` - the `biblatex` support is currently patchy.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I'll do that.